# Cyrillic \uppercase in \addcontentsline

Tags: cyrillic

I can't add uppercase string in cyrillic into table of contents in my bi-lingual document. Here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\newif\ifeng
\def\rus{\selectlanguage{russian}\engfalse}
\def\eng{\selectlanguage{english}\engtrue}
\def\UpperCase#1{\ifeng\uppercase{#1}\else\lowercase{#1}\fi}
\def\section#1{\vspace{1cm plus 1cm minus .5cm}\goodbreak
    \noindent{\bf\large\UpperCase{#1}}%
    \ifeng\addcontentsline{entoc}{section}{\UpperCase{#1}}\else%
    \addcontentsline{rutoc}{section}{\UpperCase{#1}}\fi\par\nopagebreak
    }
\def\subsection#1{\goodbreak
    \noindent{\bf\large #1}%
    \ifeng\addcontentsline{entoc}{subsection}{#1}\else%
    \addcontentsline{rutoc}{subsection}{#1}\fi\par\nopagebreak}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\pagebreak\selectlanguage{russian}
    \noindent{\bf\large СОДЕРЖАНИЕ}\@starttoc{rutoc}
    \vspace{2em}\selectlanguage{english}
    \noindent{\bf\large CONTENTS}\@starttoc{entoc}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\rus\section{Русский}
\subsection{Подсекция}
Текст
\eng\section{English}
\subsection{Subsection}
Text
\end{document}
```

(It is strange, but to make uppercase in koi8-r I need call macro `\lowercase` and vice versa).

But on command `\rus\section{Русский}` in file `\jobname.rutoc` I see `\contentsline {section}{\lowercase {\IeC {\CYRR }\IeC {\cyru }\IeC {\cyrs }\IeC {\cyrs }\IeC {\cyrk }\IeC {\cyri }\IeC {\cyrish
rt }}}{1}`.

What should I do to get right uppercase in table of contents?

Comment: You should use `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase`, not `\uppercase` and `\lowercase`.

Comment: @egreg, no, these commands don't work at all! No changes on russian text.

Comment: Please make a fully compilable example that shows failure.

Comment: @egreg, I edit question and add fully compilable example.

Comment: Are you really tied to `koi8-r`?

Comment: @egreg, yes. Only koi8-r. Never unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\MakeUppercase` and not `\uppercase`, but you have also to explicitly load `fontenc` with the `T2A` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\newif\ifeng
\def\rus{\selectlanguage{russian}\engfalse}
\def\eng{\selectlanguage{english}\engtrue}
\def\section#1{\vspace{1cm plus 1cm minus .5cm}\goodbreak
    \noindent{\bf\large\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
    \ifeng\addcontentsline{entoc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\else%
    \addcontentsline{rutoc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\fi\par\nopagebreak
    }
\def\subsection#1{\goodbreak
    \noindent{\bf\large #1}%
    \ifeng\addcontentsline{entoc}{subsection}{#1}\else%
    \addcontentsline{rutoc}{subsection}{#1}\fi\par\nopagebreak}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\pagebreak\selectlanguage{russian}
    \noindent{\bf\large СОДЕРЖАНИЕ}\@starttoc{rutoc}
    \vspace{2em}\selectlanguage{english}
    \noindent{\bf\large CONTENTS}\@starttoc{entoc}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\rus\section{Русский}
\subsection{Подсекция}
Текст
\eng\section{English}
\subsection{Subsection}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't understand the restriction to `koi8-r`; however, this works also with `utf8` in the same way.

Comment: Thank you! That's weird, but `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` really gives right results!

Comment: @Eddy_Em The `babel-russian` module just changes the encoding, but the correspondence between upper and lower case is made in `t2aenc.def` that without calling `fontenc` is not read in.